# modulation transfer function and ground resolved distance

Tags: image-processing, modulation, nyquist, resolution

I am trying to understand something in remote sensing but lack a background in science and technology so it is difficult. Hopefully this is a reasonable question to ask.

In sensing there are different definitions of resolution. One of these is Ground Sample Distance (GSD), measuring the size of the pixel subtended on the ground. Another definition is the Ground Resolved Distance (GRD), which is often the preferred metric.

One way I have seen to calculate this value is with point or edge spread functions. Papers I see show the GSD multiplied by the point or edge spread function to get a measure of GRD. The most common value I see cited though is the Modulation Transfer Function (MTF). I am not understanding what to do with this value to get a measure of GRD. Like if there is an MTF of .5 what do you do with the number to find GRD? Other than using it to calculate a spread function I mean.

[image: Example of the concept]

Comment: An MTF, like the name suggests, is not a single number, but a function, so it's not that easy. Could you explain where that figure you have in your question comes from and how it relates to your question? I'm a bit confused by it, because it adds another couple of terms that might be new to you, and doesn't necessarily fit the same framework that you are trying to understand. Generally, I think you might have jumped to too many conclusions before asking this question here, and now it's a bit hard to guess what the first thing is you actually need to correct.

Comment: Sure I can provide a link. https://medium.com/sentinel-hub/the-most-misunderstood-words-in-earth-observation-d0106adbe4b0

Comment: Indeed, it is a function. I often see values such as MTF10 or MTF 50 which I believe is the resolution at different levels of impulse responses. Basically, I read that metrics like MTF and spread functions are used to characterize image sharpness for ground resolved distance. The way I see to use a spread function is to multiply the function at full width half maximum by ground sample distance to get the ground resolved distance. I am wondering what can be done to an MTF value like MTF 10 to get a ground resolved distance estimate, as it is related to the spread functions.